# Comparing dissimilar previous row values in large Pandas DataFrame for complicated if conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame with **more than 1 million rows**, and I want to compare dissimilar previous row values in large Pandas DataFrame for complicated if conditions.

For example, I have the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[3, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], [4, 3, 5]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
print(df)

    A   B   C
0   3   2   3
1   2   2   3
2   2   1   3
3   4   3   5
```

Now, I need to add a new column and assign it the value of 1 or -1 on the basis of the following conditions:

1. if `A=B` then `D=-1`
2. if `A=C` then `D=+1`
3. if `A` is not equal to `B` or `C`, then `A` should be compared to the previous value that is different, and if `A` is bigger than its different previous value then `D=+1`, and if `A` is smaller than its different previous value then `D=-1`

The result should look like this:

```py
    A   B   C   D
0   3   2   3   1
1   2   2   3  -1
2   2   1   3  -1
3   4   3   5   1
```

Here's what I have tried:

1. Using **for-loop** (It works, but it takes ages to complete the task for a data frame with more than 1 million rows):

```py
def my_func(df):
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        n = 1
        if (df.loc[i, 'A'] == df.loc[i, 'C']):
            df.loc[i, 'D'] = 1
        elif (df.loc[i, 'A'] == df.loc[i, 'B']):
            df.loc[i, 'D'] = -1
        elif ((df.loc[i, 'A'] != df.loc[i, 'C']) & 
                (df.loc[i, 'A'] != df.loc[i, 'B'])):
            if (df.loc[i, 'A'] > df.loc[i-n, 'A']):
                df.loc[i, 'D'] = 1
            elif (df.loc[i, 'A'] < df.loc[i-n, 'A']):
                df.loc[i, 'D'] = -1
            else:
                while (df.loc[i, 'A'] == df.loc[i-n, 'A']):
                    n += 1
                    if (df.loc[i, 'A'] == df.loc[i-n, 'A']):
                        continue
                    elif (df.loc[i, 'A'] > df.loc[i-n, 'A']):
                        df.loc[i, 'D'] = 1
                        break
                    elif (df.loc[i, 'A'] < df.loc[i-n, 'A']):
                        df.loc[i, 'D'] = -1
                        break
my_func(df)
print(df)

    A   B   C   D
0   3   2   3   1
1   2   2   3  -1
2   2   1   3  -1
3   4   3   5   1
```

2. Using **`np.select`** (The result is not I want):

```py
conditions = [
    (df.A == df.B),
    (df.A == df.C),
    ((df.A != df.B) | (df.A != df.C)) & (df.A > df.A.shift()),
    ((df.A != df.B) | (df.A != df.C)) & (df.A < df.A.shift())
]
choices = [-1, 1, 1, -1]
df['D'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
print(df)

    A   B   C   D
0   3   2   3   1
1   2   2   3  -1
2   2   1   3  NaN
3   4   3   5   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example takes a slice of the 10 last values in the `A` column to find the first the first different value, which speeds up the code significantly. Of course you can change that number.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[3, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], [4, 3, 5]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

def calculate(row):
    if row['A'] == row['C']:
        value = 1
    elif row['A'] == row['C']:
        value = -1
    else:
        index = df.index.get_loc(row.name)
        if index == 0:
            return None
        previous_data = df['A'][index - 10:index].values[::-1] #get last 10 values of column A in reversed order
        last_different_value = previous_data[(previous_data != row['A']).argmax()] #get first different value
        if row['A'] > last_different_value:
            value = 1
        elif row['A'] < last_different_value:
            value = -1
        else:
            value = None
    return value

df['D'] = df.apply(calculate, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   3   2   3   1
1   2   2   3   -1
2   2   1   3   -1
3   4   3   5   1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this approach solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution out using two row iterations, the first one making an aux column in the case when A != B and A != C, the second one for using the condition to compute D.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[3, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], [4, 3, 5]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

def get_last_different(s):
    current = s.iloc[-1]
    filtered = s.loc[s != current]
    if filtered.empty:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return filtered.iloc[-1]
    return last

def compute_D(row):
    d = 0
    if row["A"] == row["B"]:
        d -= 1
    if row["A"] == row["C"]:
        d += 1
    if (row["A"] != row["B"]) and (row["A"] != row["C"]):
        if row["A"] > row["aux"]:
            d += 1
        if row["A"] < row["aux"]:
            d -= 1
    return d

df["aux"] = df.expanding(min_periods=1)["A"].apply(get_last_different)
df["D"] = df.apply(foo, axis=1)
```

At least I got your expected result. Let me know if this approach works well.

Comment: Thanks, it works but it still takes a lot of time to complete the task.